# Django custom model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My models.py

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 # Create your models here.

 class Person(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
     #first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     #last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     #username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     buisness_name= models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
```

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
from first_app.models import Person
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password')

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Person
        fields = ('buisness_name',)
```

I want to create a custom model with field `password` and `username` so when logged in it should check the username and password from this field, datas are entered manually in the fields. so how should i give login authentication.

Comment: why you are not going for built-in authentication?? and then if you want to enter data manually use Django admin to create a user by manual data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use model `User` which is already existing in django. Using that model you can create a form for that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

> models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

        def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
            if not email:
                raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
            now = timezone.now()
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            user = self.model(
                email=email,
                is_staff=is_staff,
                is_active=True,
                is_superuser=is_superuser,
                last_login=now,
                date_joined=now,
                **extra_fields

            )
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)

            return user

        def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
            return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

        def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
            user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
            return user


    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

        objects = UserManager()

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from .forms import SignUpForm, LoginForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



class UserView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(request, email=user.email, password=raw_password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
            else:
                print("user is not authenticated")
            return render(request, 'users/login.html')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})


@csrf_protect
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Gather the username and password provided by the user.
        # This information is obtained from the login form.
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        print("auth", str(authenticate(username=email, password=password)))
        if user:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'users/index.html')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("User is logged in")
        else:
            # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
            msg = "Invalid login credentials. Try Again"
            contextt = LoginForm(request)
            return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'msg': msg})

    else:
        logout(request)
        contextt = LoginForm(request)
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': contextt})




def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Home Page ")

def user_logout(request):
    print('Loggin out {}'.format(request.user))
    logout(request)
    print(request.user)
    return user_login(request)

#@login_required(login_url=user_login)
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'users/index.html')
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from .models import User


#class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
 #   class Meta:
  #      model = User
   #     fields = ('name', 'email', )

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)
```

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.as_p }}

  <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if msg %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ msg|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    First name: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```